# Incorrect parsing of date strings in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, sql, date

I'm trying to convert a string formatted date in UTC to a date object which is resulting a conversion that is off by a couple of minutes.

```
SimpleDateFormat fullDateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS", Locale.US);
fullDateFormater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Before Parsing the date string is -  `2014-07-07T18:24:23.788810`

After Parsing the Date is `Tue Jul 08 00:07:31 GMT+05:30 2014`

The correct date conversion is `Tue Jul 07 23:54:23 GMT+05:30 2014`

There is a difference of about 12-13 minutes in the conversion. I have observed a difference in the range of 10 minutes in the conversion.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: what is your input String date

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`SSSSSS` is parsing a number of milliseconds - not microseconds, as you're expecting.

788810 milliseconds is 13 minutes, 8 seconds and 810 milliseconds. So your result is actually 2014-07-07T18:27:31.810.

Yes, this is a really stupid bit of API design. It would make *much* more sense for `S...S` to mean "fractions of a second" instead of "milliseconds" - but it's far from the worst thing about the pre-Java-8 date/time API :(

I don't *think* there's a way to parse microseconds with `SimpleDateFormat` - the precision of Java time APIs pre-Java-8 is milliseconds anyway - so I think you'll just need to chop off the last three digits with `substring` and parse it using `SSS` at the end of your format string.

If you're using Java 8, I'd strongly encourage you to embrace `java.time`, which I'm sure can handle this situation. (I haven't looked at its parsing API, but I'm sure it'll be fine.)

Comment: Thanks! I almost remembered I had faced this issue before. I just dropped the milliseconds part. Not using Java 8 yet. Thanks for 'java.time'.

Comment: Indeed `java.time` parsing API is fine and correctly handles “fractions of a second” (0 through 9 digits) rather than “milliseconds”. I warmly recommend it. Look to the `DateTimeFormatter` class.