# Format of time is incorrect

Tags: java, time, formatting, duration

```
String realTimeStr = "5.2345";
Double realTimeDbl = Double.parseDouble(realTimeStr);
long   realTimeLng = (long) (realTimeDbl*1000);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSSS", Locale.getDefault());      
log("Duration: " + sdf.format(new Date(realTimeLng - TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset())));
```

Current output:

> Duration: 00:00:05.0234

Desired output:

> Duration: 00:00:05.2345

I also tried another method, still no good:

```
String realTimeStr = "1.4345";
Double realTimeDbl = Double.parseDouble(realTimeStr);               
DateTimeFormatter formatter =               
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSSS").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));            
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli((long)(realTimeDbl*1000));
String t = formatter.format(instant);
System.out.println("Duration: " + t);
```

Current output:

> Duration: 00:00:01.4340

Desired output:

> Duration: 00:00:01.4345

I have googled for some time. Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: Milliseconds, by definition, cannot be more than three digits.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` has milliseconds precision (only 3 digits after decimal point). With more than 3 (like you're trying with `SSSS`), it simply gets lost and returns [strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24617644/7605325). And I think you're also mistaking a time of the day (hour/minute/secs, such as `10 AM` or `5:30 PM`) with a duration (an [amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44676793/7605325), such as *"2 days, 3 hours and 15 minutes"* or *"10 years and 3 months"*). Although both use the same words ("hours", "minutes", etc), they're not the same thing

Comment: Also, when you multiply `realTimeDbl` by 1000 and cast it to a `long`, the value is rounded to `5234` (you lose the last digit). But this won't work anyway because of `SimpleDateFormat`'s limitation to 3 decimal digits.

Comment: anyway we can get 4 decimal digits?

Comment: Not with `SimpleDateFormat`. And after your edit: you're still treating the duration as a date/time, when it's not. There's no built-in formatter for a duration, you'll probably have to do it manually

Comment: And once again you are casting to long, losing the last digit...

Comment: As Hugo has already said, there is no built-in duration formatter, but maybe you find [following example](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/69ee60a59544f44ce45810e3ed7db86a) for a duration formatter with my lib Time4J interesting (it manages four digits behind the decimal point, too).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're mistaking 2 different concepts:

1. A **time of the day**, such as `10 AM` or `15:30:45`
2. A **duration**, which is an [amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662242/is-there-a-name-for-date-time-interval-format-like-1h10m/44676793#44676793), such as *1 year, 2 months and 10 days* or *10 hours, 25 minutes and 30 seconds*

Although both might use the same words (such as "hours" and "minutes"), they're not the same thing. A **duration** is not attached to a chronology (10 hours and 25 minutes relative to what?), it's just the amount of time, by itself.

`SimpleDateFormat` and `DateTimeFormatter` are designed to format **dates and times of the day**, but not durations. Although converting a duration to a time and "pretending" it's a time of the day to format it might work, it's not the right way.

Unfortunately, there are no built-in formatters for a duration. So you'll have to format it manually.

Another detail is that you are multiplying `1.4345` by 1000 (resulting in `1434.5`), and then **casting** to a `long`(so the value is rounded to `1434`) - the last digit is lost.

One way to do it is to parse the string to a double and then multiply by 1 billion to get the value as nanoseconds (I don't know if you'll work with more than 4 digits, so I'm considering nanosecond precision):

```
// convert the string value to a total of nanoseconds
int nanosPerSecond = 1_000_000_000;
long nanos = (long) (Double.parseDouble(realTimeStr) * nanosPerSecond);
```

Now we must format it manually. First I've extracted the number of hours, minutes, seconds and nanoseconds from the total nanos value:

```
long hours = nanos / nanosPerSecond / 3600;
nanos -= hours * 3600 * nanosPerSecond;
long minutes = nanos / nanosPerSecond / 60;
nanos -= minutes * 60 * nanosPerSecond;
long seconds = nanos / nanosPerSecond;
nanos -= seconds * nanosPerSecond;
```

Then I created an auxiliary method to build the output:

```
// auxiliary method
public void addValue(long value, StringBuilder sb) {
    if (value < 10) {
        sb.append("0");
    }
    sb.append(value);
}
```

And used it to join the pieces:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
addValue(hours, sb);
sb.append(":");
addValue(minutes, sb);
sb.append(":");
addValue(seconds, sb);
sb.append(".");
addValue(nanos, sb);

// remove the extra zeroes in the end
String output = sb.toString().replaceAll("0*$", "");
System.out.println(output);
```

The output is:

> 00:00:01.4345

Comment: Thanks. Ill work with 3 digits for now and if need be ill use the method described here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String realTimeStr = "5.2345";
        Double realTimeDbl = Double.parseDouble(realTimeStr);
        long nanos = (long) (realTimeDbl * 1000_000_000);
        Duration duration = Duration.ofNanos(nanos);
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedDuration = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%d", duration.toHours() % 24,
                duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60, (duration.toNanos() % 1000_000_000) / 100000);
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedDuration = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart(), duration.toNanosPart() / 100000);
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT5.2345S
00:00:05.2345
00:00:05.2345
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides in the format, as noticed by Joe C, probably meaning at this line:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSSS", Locale.getDefault());
```

try changing it removing one "S"

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.getDefault());
```

notify us if it's correct =)

Comment: yes it is correct. thanks. but would like 4 decimal digits.

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.stackoverflow.examples;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeStamp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String realTimeStr = "5.2345";
        Double realTimeDbl = Double.parseDouble(realTimeStr);
        long realTimeLng = (long) (realTimeDbl * 1000);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSSs", Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println("Duration: " + sdf.format(new Date(realTimeLng - TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset())));
    }
}
```

I tried `SSSs` instead of `SSSS`

Comment: Why would you put a second pattern character `s` among the milliseconds?

Comment: hah! it knew it was something simple. the part that doesnt make sense is the comments above are claiming that milliseconds in SimpleDateFormat goes up to 3 digits. so how is it that this worked?

Comment: I know SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSSa", Locale.getDefault()); will give Duration: 00:00:05.234AM so tried the small s. I am not sure of this please check it

Comment: This answer is complete nonsense. @user1798810, the small `s` in the format represent seconds regardless of the fact that it follow the `S`, the milliseconds. You're just copying the `5` from the seconds into your millisecond representation. It doesn't _mean_ what you think it means.

Comment: ok, i will look into it. looks like im getting some odd results in the end. for now i will settle with 3 sig. digits. thx @Sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: @user1798810 Note also that a `Date` doesn't represent a duration. It's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis tried using duration and wasnt really successful. But yes, i agree.

Comment: @javalearner_heaven Just test your code with the input `1.4345` and you'll see that it doesn't work. As already said, appending a `s` to the end just prints again the *seconds* value (which in this case will be `1`). `SimpleDateFormat` simply can't handle more than 3 decimal digits.

Comment: Unbelievable that there are some upvoters for this wrong answer. Never use `SimpleDateFormat` for printing durations, see the good remarks of Hugo.