# Issues Converting String dates into Long values and performing calculations

Tags: java, date, long-integer, duration, string-parsing

I have a map of string values which represent down times for different components.

```
dependencyMap.put ("sut", "14:26:12,14:27:19,00:01:07;15:01:54,15:02:54,00:01:00;15:44:30,15:46:30,00:02:00;16:10:30,16:11:30,00:01:00");
dependencyMap.put ("jms", "14:26:12,14:28:12,00:02:00;15:10:50,15:12:55,00:02:05;15:42:30,15:43:30,00:01:00;16:25:30,16:27:30,00:02:00");
```

The strings represent the start, end and duration of down times.

```
(start)14:26:12,(end)14:27:19,(duration)00:01:07
```

I read the values in, then add them to a list of `DependencyDownTime` objects which hold the `Long` values startTime, endTime and duration.

```
jArray.forEach (dependency ->{
            String downTimeValues = knownDowntimesMap.get(dependency);
            final String[] downtime = downTimeValues.split (";");
            for (final String str : downtime) {
                final DependencyDownTime depDownTime = new DependencyDownTime ();
                final String[] strings = str.split (",");
                if (strings.length == 3) {
                    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("HH:mm:ss");
                    try {
                        depDownTime.setStartTime(dateFormat.parse (strings[0]).getTime ());
                        depDownTime.setEndTime (dateFormat.parse (strings[1]).getTime ());
                        depDownTime.setDuration (dateFormat.parse (strings[2]).getTime ());
                        downTimes.add (depDownTime);
                    } catch (final ParseException e) {
                        //logger.warn (e.getMessage (), e);
                    }
                } else {
                    //logger.warn ("");
                }
            }
```

I then perform simple arithmetic on the values, which calculates the total down time for each component.

```
// sort the list by start time
        Collections.sort(downTimes, Comparator.comparing (DependencyDownTime::getStartTime));

        int i = 1;
        Long duration = 0L;
        for(DependencyDownTime dts: downTimes){
            Long curStart = dts.getStartTime ();
            Long curEnd = dts.getEndTime();

            Long nextStart = downTimes.get(i).getStartTime ();
            Long nextEnd = downTimes.get(i).getEndTime ();

            if(duration == 0){
                duration = dts.getDuration();
            }
            if(curStart.equals(nextStart) && curEnd < nextEnd){
                duration += (nextEnd - curEnd);
            }
            else if(nextStart > curEnd){
                duration += downTimes.get(i).getDuration();
            }
            else if( curStart < nextStart && curEnd > nextStart){
                duration += (nextEnd - curEnd);
            }
            else if(curEnd == nextStart){
                duration += downTimes.get(i).getDuration();
            }
            i++;
            if(i == downTimes.size ()){
                componentDTimeMap.put (application, duration);
                return;
            }
```

The expected values should be something like `1970-01-01T 00:14:35 .000+0100`, a matter of minutes. The actual result is usually extremely high off by a matter of hours in the difference `1969-12-31T 15:13:35 .000+0100`

I have 2 questions.

1. Am I parsing the values correctly?
2. If my calculations are a little off when adding and subtracting the long values. When I convert the values back to Date format will there be a drastic difference in the expected value?

Comment: there is so much that can go wrong with string parsing to dates. Simply i would suggest using [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to do date string manipulations

Comment: According to Joda time website, you should use the JAVA 8 date library. Because Joda time core is integrated to Java 8 :)

Comment: @Augustas  I will look into it thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me. `"14:26:12,14:27:19,00:01:07;15:01:54,15:02:54,00:01:00;15:44:30,15:46:30,00:02:00;16:10:30,16:11:30,00:01:00"` means what? I understood that between 14:26:12 and 14:27:19 the system was down (total downtime 1 minute and 7 seconds), then between 15:01:54 and 15:02:54, it's another downtime, and so on. So you should just sum the durations? I didn't understand your if-elses logic, what should be the result?

Comment: @Hugo the logic is a bit more complex than the question states. We are calculating the down time for each application, each application can have multiple dependencies, such as postgres, jms, sut. The way we calculate the DT is by comparing start and end times, with the next downtime period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46113091/7605325), don't mistake those 2 different concepts:

- a **time of the day**: it represents a specific point of a day, such as `10 AM` or `14:45:50`
- a **duration**: it represents an [amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662242/is-there-a-name-for-date-time-interval-format-like-1h10m/44676793#44676793), such as "1 hour and 10 minutes" or "2 years, 3 months and 4 days". The duration doesn't tell you when it starts or ends ("1 hour and 10 minutes" relative to what?), it's not attached to a chronology, it doesn't correspond to a specific point in the timeline. It's just the amount of time, by itself.

In your input, you have:

```
(start)14:26:12,(end)14:27:19,(duration)00:01:07
```

The `start` and `end` represents **times of the day**, and the `duration` represents the **amount of time**. `SimpleDateFormat` is designed to work with dates and times of the day, but not with durations. Treating the duration as a time of the day might work, but it's a hack as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46113522/7605325).

Another problem is that when `SimpleDateFormat` parses only a time, it defaults the day to January 1<sup>st</sup> 1970 at the JVM default timezone, leading to all the strange results you see. Unfortunately there's no way to avoid that, as `java.util.Date` works with full timestamps. A better alternative is to use the new date/time API.

As in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46113091/7605325) you're using Java 8, I'm assuming you can also use it here (but if you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. The only difference is the **package names** (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same).

As you're working only with times, there's no need to consider date fields (day/month/year), we can use a `LocalTime` instead. You can parse the strings directly, because they are in [ISO861 compliant format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times):

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("14:26:12");
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("14:27:19");
```

Unfortunately there are no built-in parsers for a duration, so you'll have to parse it manually:

```
// parse the duration manually
String[] parts = "00:01:07".split(":");
Duration d = Duration
    // get hours
    .ofHours(Long.parseLong(parts[0]))
    // plus minutes
    .plusMinutes(Long.parseLong(parts[1]))
    // plus seconds
    .plusSeconds(Long.parseLong(parts[2]));
```

Another alternative is to remove the durations from your input (or ignore them) and calculate it using the start and end:

```
Duration d = Duration.between(start, end);
```

Both will give you a duration of 1 minute and 7 seconds.

My suggestion is to change the `DependencyDownTime` to store start and end as `LocalTime` objects, and the duration as a `Duration` object. With this, your algorithm would be like this:

```
Duration total = Duration.ZERO;
for (...) {
    LocalTime curStart = ...
    LocalTime curEnd = ...
    LocalTime nextStart = ...
    LocalTime nextEnd = ...

    if (total.toMillis() == 0) {
        duration = dts.getDuration();
    }
    if (curStart.equals(nextStart) && curEnd.isBefore(nextEnd)) {
        total = total.plus(Duration.between(curEnd, nextEnd));
    } else if (nextStart.isAfter(curEnd)) {
        total = total.plus(downTimes.get(i).getDuration());
    } else if (curStart.isBefore(nextStart) && curEnd.isAfter(nextStart)) {
        total = total.plus(Duration.between(curEnd, nextEnd));
    } else if (curEnd.equals(nextStart)) {
        total = total.plus(downTimes.get(i).getDuration());
    }
    i++;
    if (i == downTimes.size()) {
        // assuming you want the duration as a total of milliseconds
        componentDTimeMap.put(application, total.toMillis());
        return;
    }
}
```

You can either store the `Duration` object, or the respective value of milliseconds. Don't try to transform it to a `Date`, because a date is not designed nor supposed to work with durations. You can [adapt this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46084708/7605325) to format a duration if you want (unfortunately there are no native formatters for durations).

---

## Limitations

The code above assumes that all `start` and `end` times are in the same day. But if you have `start` at `23:50` and `end` at `00:10`, should the duration be 20 minutes?

If that's the case, it's a little bit trickier, because `LocalTime` is not aware of the date (so it considers `23:50 > 00:10` and the duration between them is "minus 23 hours and 40 minutes").

In this case, you could do a trick and assume the dates are all at the current date, but when `start` is greater than `end`, it means that `end` time is in the next day:

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("23:50");
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("00:10");
// calculate duration
Duration d;
if (start.isAfter(end)) {
    // start is after end, it means end is in the next day

    // current date
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    // start is at the current day
    LocalDateTime startDt = now.atTime(start);
    // end is at the next day
    LocalDateTime endDt = now.plusDays(1).atTime(end);
    d = Duration.between(startDt, endDt);
} else {
    // both start and end are in the same day
    // just calculate the duration in the usual way
    d = Duration.between(start, end);
}
```

In the code above, the result will be a `Duration` of 20 minutes.

---

## Don't format dates as durations

Here are some examples of why `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` aren't good to handle durations of time.

Suppose I have a duration of 10 seconds. If I try to transform it to a `java.util.Date` using the value 10 to a date (AKA treating a duration as a date):

```
// a 10 second duration (10000 milliseconds), treated as a date
Date date = new Date(10 * 1000);
System.out.println(date);
```

This will get a date that corresponds to "10000 milliseconds after unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`)", which is `1970-01-01T00:00:10Z`. But when I print the date object, the `toString()` method is implicity called (as explained **[here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/)**). And this method converts this millis value to the JVM default timezone.

In the JVM I'm using, the default timezone is `America/Sao_Paulo`, so the code above outputs:

> Wed Dec 31 21:00:10 BRT 1969

Which is not what is expected: the UTC instant `1970-01-01T00:00:10Z` corresponds to December 31<sup>st</sup> 1969 at 9 PM in São Paulo timezone.

This happens because I'm erroneously treating the duration as a date (and the output will be different, depending on the default timezone configured in the JVM).

A `java.util.Date` can't (must not) be used to work with durations. Actually, now that we have [better API's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime), it should be avoided whenever possible. There are [too many problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api) with this, just don't use it if you can.

---

`SimpleDateFormat` also won't work properly if you handle the durations as dates. In this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date d = dateFormat.parse("10:00:00");
```

The input has only time fields (hour, minute and second), so `SimpleDateFormat` sets the date to January 1<sup>st</sup> 1970 at the JVM default timezone. If I `System.out.println` this date, the result will be:

> Thu Jan 01 10:00:00 BRT 1970

That's January 1<sup>st</sup> 1970 at 10 AM in São Paulo timezone, which in UTC is equivalent to `1970-01-01T13:00:00Z` - so `d.getTime()` returns `46800000`.

If I change the JVM default timezone to `Europe/London`, it will create a date that corresponds to January 1<sup>st</sup> 1970 at 10 AM in London (or UTC `1970-01-01T09:00:00Z`) - and `d.getTime()` now returns `32400000` (because 10 AM in London and 10 AM in São Paulo happened at different instants).

`SimpleDateFormat` isn't the right tool to work with durations - [it isn't even the best tool to work with dates](https://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/sdf/), actually.

Comment: This really is an excellent answer to not just one, but 2 questions. I have read a lot of different articles and questions which cover many of the individual topics, which make up my problem. But you have given me a really great understanding of the problem and filled in a gap in my knowledge. I had never really grasped the concept of Date vs Duration. Again thanks.