# Issue Converting seconds to HH:MM:SS java

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, long-integer

I have a long variable which represents the downtime of an application in seconds. I want to display the downtime as `HH:mm:ss`

```
Long downTime = 755; 
Date newD = new Date(downTime * 1000);
```

When passing the long variable to the Date I multiplied it `1000` to get the millisecond value. The `newD` variable evaluates to `Thu Jan 01 01:12:35 GMT 1970`

The value of `newD` is off by 1 hour, 755 seconds is = 00:12:35

It was my understanding that seconds * 1000 = milliseconds will evaluate to the correct answer. As [I seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/java-convert-long-to-date)

If I use Duration we get the right answer.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds(downTime);
PT12M35S
```

But the formatting is not as I want it.

Comment: Take a look here for how to format duration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss.

Comment: Your current code would work if you were in UTC, your local timezone must be one hour ahead of UTC.

Comment: Also, if you have access to the Duration class, it means you're using Java 8. So don't use the old Date class anymore. Use classes from the java.time package.

Comment: try using `Date newD = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + downTime * 1000);` that should provide you the system's current time.

Comment: Just saying, but if you use `java.time.Duration`, at least use complete the `java.time` package, not `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @procrastinator The Question is not asking for the current time at all. The Question is about hacking a time-of-day format for a span-of-time. Also, avoid the legacy classes. Much easier to just use the modern java.time classes. `LocalTime.MIN.plusSeconds( 755L ).toString()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `LocalTime.MIN`

```
LocalTime.MIN.plusSeconds( 755L )
```

Or,

```
LocalTime.MIN.plus( 
    Duration.ofSeconds( 755L ) 
)
```

**CAVEAT:** This is a hack, and I do not recommend it. Representing a span-of-time as a time-of-day is ambiguous and confusing.

By default, the [`LocalTime::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#toString--) method omits the trailing units if zero. To force all three parts (hours, minutes, seconds), use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HH:mm:ss" ) ;
String output = lt.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/lZrKcR).

> 00:12:35

## ISO 8601

I suggest, if possible, to train your users on the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format. This format is practical, clear, and unambiguous. The standard formats are used by default in the java.time classes for parsing/generating strings.

> PT12M35S

Or generate a string spelling out the amount of time in prose.

Comment: I agree that this hack could be confusing. `Duration` exist (and is know by OP) to represent a duration... using it it the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you can use this:

```
long millis = 755000;
String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));
System.out.println(hms);
```

Answer (score 0):

### You are almost there

[`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

If you have gone through the above links, you might have already noticed that `PT12M35S` specifies a duration of 12 minutes 35 seconds. Since you have already got `Duration` object, out of this object, you can create a string formatted as per your requirement by getting days, hours, minutes, seconds from it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long downTime = 755L;
        Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(downTime);// PT12M35S

        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHours() % 24,
                duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT12M35S
00:12:35
00:12:35
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

### Duration and date are different concepts

Your requirement is to calculate the duration instead of a date-time. `SimpleDateFormat` or `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` (part of the modern date-time API) should be used to represent a date/time/date-time i.e. something which represents a point in time instead of a period/duration of time. A thumb rule to remember this is:

1. Use `SimpleDateFormat` or `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` for something which you refer with `since` in English grammar Tense.
2. Use [Period and Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) for something which you refer with `for` in English grammar Tense.

Check [The Difference between Since and For – English grammar](https://www.wallstreetenglish.com/blog/the-difference-between-since-and-for-english-grammar-with-exercises/)